# react-google-maps: MarkerWithLabel AND InfoWindow?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I've been trying to get MarkerWithLabel to work with InfoWindow but it doesn't seem to be working since MarkerWithLabel expects only a single child.

which is the label where Marker accepts a single child which is the InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct in that `MarkerWithLabel` can only have one child and hence can't have an `InfoWindow` as a child.

The current workaround as per [this comment](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/748#issuecomment-360683226) involves rendering the `InfoWindow` next to the `Marker` in the component structure, both with the same position. There's also an [open PR](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/pull/759).

In any case, this library is deprecated now so I recommend you use [react-google-maps-api](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/tree/master/packages/react-google-maps-api) instead.

Hope this helps!